# Passport returns 500 error (without response ) when wrong access token is sent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-authorization

I'm using Laravel/Passport for authentication for my REST-API.

I have my app set up localy, and on a test server and I've already configured Passport.

I'have my routes protected with `auth:api` guard , but i've noticed that when i want to access protected route & wrong/expired access token is provided in the header  ( `Authorization`:`Beraer <wrong_token>` ), it returns 500 error with no response at all.

This happens only on the test server ( localy it works perfect ). I've tried to re-configure Passport , cleared caches, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Check your server error logs

Comment: I've looked at the `storage/logs/laravel.log` file and there is nothing helpful. Last error occurred an hour ago ( it's not related ).

Comment: Sorry for fast response, i've found this error log : `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Exception/OAuthServerException.php on line 168`

Answer (score 3):

so i found the acctual issue here on github https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/440 and as a solution, you can add `\League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException::class,` to the `$dontReport` array ( probably this occured , because i've updated passport package )